# Text of Text Box resets when I go to other pages

Tags: c#, uwp

After writing In the `TextBox`, I go to my `SettingsPage` and when I go back from there, my text is reset.

Code to navigate to `SettingsPage` from `MainPage`:

```cs
if (Window.Current.Content is Frame rootFrame)
{
    rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(SettingsPage));
}
```

Code to navigate to `MainPage` from `SettingsPage`:

```cs
if (Window.Current.Content is Frame rootFrame && rootFrame.CanGoBack)
{
    rootFrame.GoBack();
}
```

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the cache mode in the page to "required" to maintain the content:

In your mainpage.xaml:

```xml
<Page
...
NavigationCacheMode="Required">
```

Here the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.navigation.navigationcachemode?view=winrt-22621)